# Reusability of XPath with different name

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a modal, within that modal there are various card. Those cards have dropdown. It looks some what like the screenshot below. They all have different select name. Is there any way to write a method in C# so I dont have to do //select[@name='test1a']or //select[@name='test1b'] for all dropdown?

[image]

HTML Code below

```
<table class="row-inner-table" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row-content">
            <td class="field-name">test1a</td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <select name="test-4" onchange="calc(document.myForm.TOTAL_8,this,24)">
                    <option value="" score="0"> </option>
                    <option value="118" score="0">test1b </option>
                    <option value="124" score="1">test1c</option>
                    <option value="120" score="2">test1d</option>
                </select>
                <input type="HIDDEN" name="PREVIOUS_24" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-content">
            <td class="field-name">test2</td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <select name="test-5" onchange="calc(document.myForm.TOTAL_8,this,25)">
                    <option value="" score="0"> </option>
                    <option value="121" score="0">hi</option>
                    <option value="113" score="1">hello</option>
                    <option value="114" score="2">C ya </option>
                </select>
                <input type="HIDDEN" name="PREVIOUS_25" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-content">
            <td class="field-name">test 3</td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <select name="test-6" onchange="calc(document.myForm.TOTAL_8,this,26)">
                    <option value="" score="0"> </option>
                    <option value="123" score="0">hehe</option>
                    <option value="112" score="1">haha</option>
                    <option value="119" score="2">001</option>
                </select>
                <input type="HIDDEN" name="PREVIOUS_26" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-content">
            <td class="field-name">test4</td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <select name="test-7" onchange="calc(document.myForm.TOTAL_8,this,27)">
                    <option value="" score="0"> </option>
                    <option value="111" score="0">404</option>
                    <option value="122" score="1">402/option>
                        <option value="117" score="2">403</option>
                </select>
                <input type="HIDDEN" name="PREVIOUS_27" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-content">
            <td class="field-name">test 5 </td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <select name="test-8" onchange="calc(document.myForm.TOTAL_8,this,28)">
                    <option value="" score="0"> </option>
                    <option value="115" score="0">Relaxed</option>
                    <option value="125" score="1">Tense, rigid</option>
                    <option value="116" score="2">Very tense or rigid</option>
                </select>
                <input type="HIDDEN" name="PREVIOUS_28" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-content-total">
            <td class="field-name total-label">Total</td>
            <td class="field-value">
                <input type="TEXT" size="5" name="TOTAL_8" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No matter what you do... you still need to be able to choose which select to edit so you have to be able to differentiate between them. The way you would do that is through a locator, e.g. using name. Can you explain why you want to do this? Making things shorter doesn't always make things easier, or easier to read, or easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as easy as something like this

```
public SelectElement dropdownElement(By locator)
{
   return new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(locator));
}
```

and you call it like

```
SelectElement select = dropdownElement(By.CssSelector("select[name='test-5']"));
```

Comment: Instead of passing in just the string name, pass in a `By` locator. That way if you decide to change how you find the element or the page is redesigned, you don't have to rewrite the method and all the tests. In this example you could use `By.CssSelector("select[name='test-5']");`

Comment: @JeffC that works too, feel free to edit that in if you want

Comment: Changed it based on my suggestion, added the missing `return` :), and added an example call.

Comment: Now that I think about it... this really should return a `SelectElement` for greater ease in using the dropdown element.

Comment: @JeffC I did not wanted  repeat same looking over and over for each drop down, Right now my code looks like this for all dropdown                                              
    public Ppage Selectdropdwon(string richmondedited)
        {

            IWebElement testdropdown = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name = 'test-4']"));
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(testdropdown);
            select.SelectByText(richmondedited);
            Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
            return this;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of C.Peck's solution which will cut down the repetitive Xpath (or CSS) string code, assuming the base of the Xpath is always the same which in the OP it appears to be

```
public SelectElement SelectMenuItem(string menuValue)
{
    var menuString = $"//select[@name='{menuValue}']";
    return new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(menuString)));
}

SelectElement selectOne = SelectMenuItem("test-4");
SelectElement selectTwo = SelectMenuItem("test-5");
```

**EDIT**:

To show you the A-Z on reusability for this, it would look something like this...

Method to return `Select Element` with dynamic `XPath` string:

```
    public SelectElement SelectMenuItem(string menuValue)
    {
        var menuString = $"//select[@name='{menuValue}']";
        return new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath(menuString)));
    }
```

Method to set value for dropdown, by `XPath`:

```
    public void SetMenuValue(string menuValue, string menuDropDown)
    {
        SelectElement select = SelectMenuItem(menuDropDown);
        select.SelectByText(menuValue);

    }
```

Finally, method to set the specific values you want, passing in `value` first, then `XPath` next:

```
    public void Input_Values()
    {
        SetMenuValue("118", "test-4");
        SetMenuValue("121", "test-5");
    }
```

You don't need that last method, you could call `SetMenuValue` from anywhere, that was just another example of how you could do this